# Detect python multiprocessing error

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, unit-testing

I'm trying to use a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()` to run some tasks in different threads (on Windows, if that matters).  I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 241, in _feed
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\Matthew\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object '_RunnerThread._make_new_task.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

I completely understand why this is happening, and I can fix it.

> But how do I detect that it's happened?

Let me explain.  I was initially testing this area of code using `pytest` and some unit tests, but what happened is that the unit test would just deadlock, taking forever to complete.  No error raised, no output captured which I could see.  It was only when I ran the application that I saw the above printed to the terminal.  But it appears to be an exception thrown in a different thread.  The `Future` I get back from the `submit` method is well-formed, and continues to claim that it's "running".

(Update: This is slightly incorrect.  If I `submit` my task, wait a little time, and then deliberately raise an Exception, then `pytest` *does* capture the `stderr` output above.  But if I just try to wait for my `Future` to complete, there is no error, just an infinite wait...)

So, from the perspective of my application, everything worked fine, just the task is taking forever to complete.  This is obviously rather annoying: I'd really like to detect that I've made this mistake from a unit test.  How can I do that?

**Edit:** A self-contained example:

```
import concurrent.futures

def func():
    return 5

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(lambda : func())]

        for result in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
            print(result.result())
```

If you run this, you get a stack-trace printed to stderr, but the script itself just runs forever.  I'd like to make it error out...

Comment: Would it be possible to explain why the vote to close?